# javascript create a new array from json results

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

It is probably a simple solution, but I can not seem to get it working :/ 
I want to create a new "response" from results collected trough json/api call.

```
jsonResponse = [
     {"_id":"1","desc":"test desc","title":"Title 1"},
     {"_id":"2","title":"Title 2","desc":"desc 2"}
    ];
```

I need to create a new array from this that looks like this;

```
var newResponse = [ 
  { "heading" : "Title 1", "summary" : "test desc"},
  { "heading" : "Title 2", "summary" : "desc 2"}

 ];
```

Stripping _id and changing "key". How can I go about doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function works wonders:

```
var newResponse = jsonResponse.map(function(item){
  return { heading : item.title, summary : item.desc };
});
```

Comment: ES5 required. This will not work on older browsers. If that is a concern.

Comment: @SaintGerbil That is explained in the link i gave, under Browser Compatibility. There is also a polyfill available for browsers which don't implement Array.prototype.map.

Comment: console throwing me a : Uncaught TypeError: Object [{"..."}] has no method 'map' (I am developing (trying to at least) a mobile app).

Comment: @Tom Could you do a `console.log(Array.prototype.map)` for me?

Comment: @Tom then the problem is that your original object is not an array. If you will update the question to provide the exact shape of jsonResponse, i would be happy to give the correct answer.

Comment: @Tom Great solution @Tibos, I'd like to add that if you're new to JS, it's handy to know what `.map()` is actually doing so you can use either based on your project API support, which you'll be able to see what it's doing internally from my example :) happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Array.prototype.map` is a great solution, but if you want to support older browsers, you can either use the `map` polyfill, or do this:

```
var newData = function () {
    var myArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < JSON.length; i++) {
        var self = JSON[i];
        myArray.push({
            heading: self.title,
            summary: self.desc
        });
    }
    return myArray;
};

// output
newData();
```

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/DEcrF)